# Asp.Net app using SQL Server CE 4.0 causes sharing exception with multiple clients

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I have an ASP.Net 4.0 website which uses SQL Server CE and EF code-first for its data store.  When 2 or more users are on the site I intermittently get the following exception about every 5th or 6th time.

> There is a file sharing violation. A different process might be using
>   the file. [D:\directory...\file.sdf].

Throughout the code I create, use, and promptly dispose of the `DbContext` each time one is needed. Even though it is the default, I have added `File Mode = Read Write` to the connection string.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that all apps accessing the file uses the same connection string?

Comment: Yes I am, the connection string exists only in the web.config file and there is only one connection string there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figure out what happened.  I found a link (unfortunately I do not recall where), that mentions that Go Daddy shared hosting uses a load balancer and multiple servers to serve the site.  Even though the database file shows up on a drive mounted with a drive letter, clearly it must be located on a file server that all the webservers share.

Using SQL CE by multiple clients over a network is a nonsupported configuration.  When I upgraded from SQL Compact to a SQL Server Instance provided by Go Daddy, the problem (and another data consistency problem I did not mention above) went away.

I am a little surprised that I did not find this problem when I googled it.  Microsoft is pmarketing SQL Compact as a good back end for small website.  If I am correct, this seems to be a significant liability in that regard.

Comment: Small websites typically run on a single server!